# Enable HTTPS on Amazon AWS for EC2, without cloudfront or load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, load-balancer

I have my ec2 instance running on HTTP on my domain.
I have created a certificate using AWS certificate manager. It is issued, but not in use. Like in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xea1G.png) (if it matters it was used DNS validation for the certificate).

I have created a security group and activated ports 80 & 443. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKZVF.png).

From the documentation I understood that I need to enable a load balancer in front of the ec2 and a cloudfront in front of the load balancer.
Because I do not have a lot of traffic at the moment, I do not require a load balancer which costs ~20$/month.

Where can I upload/link the certificate in this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Where can I upload/link the certificate in this case?*

You can't.  Unless you are using *at least one* supported service -- CloudFront, ELB, or API Gateway -- you can't use ACM certificates.  You need another strategy, not ACM -- such as [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org).

The reason for this limitation is that ACM and the services it interoperates with securely manage the private keys associated with your certificate, never exposing them to anyone *including you*.  You can't install a cert on a server (e.g. EC2) without access to the private key.

However, if you are satisfied with the traffic between the browser and CloudFront being encrypted but the traffic between CloudFront and the EC2 instance *not* being encrypted, them you can use ACM and CloudFront with EC2 and no balancer, by setting the CloudFront Origin Protocol Policy to HTTP Only.

Comment: Let's Encrypt is fairly easy, and provides end to end encryption. Using CloudFlare is even easier, and can encrypt to your server using a self signed certificate on your server.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response. It is a better solution for me to put an API gateway in front of the ec2.